# Loggining into another wordpress instance from an existing wordpress instance

Tags: wordpress, multiple-sites

I have inherited a legacy website which consists of multiple instances of WordPress installed on the server for each zone of the site. It is faced by a further instance of WordPress and users need to authenticate and log into these other Wordpress sites from the front page of the facing Wordpress site. Is it possible to log into a different instance of Wordpress when you are already running an instance? If so how can it be done?

Comment: Do you mean it is using WordPress multisite? or are there literally multiple WP installs on the same server. (i.e. is there one wp-config.php or multiple?)

Comment: It is not a multisite. There are 4 complete instances of Wordpress separate from each other.

Comment: Yikes... I'm sorry for you. I don't know of a way to log someone into multiple installs of WordPress simultaneously (even if they are on the same machine). Maybe you could try merging the 4 disparate sites into a single multisite install? I know that is possible, and it may help you with a lot of other management problems.